# android bluetooth chat application

Tags: android

I m building an android bluetooth chat application and facing some problem in it.My problem is:I m not able to detect available bluetooth devices in the range and not able to show in a list.As i m new to android programming not able to detect problem.Please help me.

My code is:

```
public class BluetoothSearchActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    TextView stateBluetooth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ImageView BluetoothSearchImageView=new ImageView(this);
        BluetoothSearchImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.inner1);

        setContentView(BluetoothSearchImageView);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_search);

        mBluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        ListView listDevicesFound=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);

        btArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (BluetoothSearchActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        listDevicesFound.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);

        registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver,new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

        btArrayAdapter.clear();
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action=intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }   
    };
```

Comment: do you have all the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the other device as discoverable? Most smartphones are invisible for paired devices at default and you need to enable visibility for it to be visible.

I see you use the example from the API reference so it should work.

Make sure you have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Other than that you have some odd naming conventions for your objects. ActionFoundReceiver should be actionFoundReceiver (its a object not a class), but no big deal.

If you get any kind of error message please post that as well.

edit: You could write out the device name and adress in a Log.d(tag, string) so you can read it out in logcat debug, eliminates a problem with displaying your list.

edit: added code for Log.d

```
import android.util.Log;

//to use Log.d(String, String)
Log.d("someTag", "your text here");
```

You can use Log.d to print debug information that helps you understand if your code is executing correctly. I would     `Log.d("tag", device.getName()+" "+device.getAddress());` to see if you are gettnig any response from the listener. And eliminate any problems you might have from trying to get it into a list etc..

--
Thomas Flølo

Comment: How do i use Log.d(tag,string)in my project.please tell me.with writing code.

Comment: I would place the code from my edit into your ActionFoundReceiver.

Comment: To view the output from Log.d you need to display the logcat window in Eclipse or use ADB from a command prompt.